# DAX Normal Distribution

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax, normal-distribution

I am looking for a function in DAX that acts similarly to the NORM.DIST function in Excel. I have an X value, the mean, and the standard deviation and I am looking to find the cumulative distribution (with an accuracy of at least six sigma).

I've searched through the official list of [DAX statistical functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634822.aspx), but I could not find any function that does this. I'm looking for the most economical way to perform this calculation. Is the [Bell approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Numerical_approximations_for_the_normal_CDF) the best way to go? This would be iterated over a table of about 10,000 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SIGN([X])*0.5*(1-(1/30)*(7*EXP(-([X]^2)/2)+16*EXP(-([X]^2)*(2-SQRT(2)))+(7+0.25*PI()*[X]^2)*EXP(-([X]^2))))^0.5+0.5
```

Given [X] is already normalized. MAX Error = .0000304

Error:

[image: Error]

Compared to previous solution:

[image: Relative Error]

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDistributionFunction.html (14)

Answer (score 0):

```
=.5*(1+SIGN([X])*(1-EXP(-2*([X])/[Sigma])^2/PI()))^.5)
```

Worked for me. This may be the fastest way, this may not. Idk.

**EDIT**

MAX Error = .0031458

[image: Error]